# Period after abbreviation

Tags: word-usage, sentences, punctuation

When I write a sentence that ends with an abbreviation, should I add the final period or omit it?

> Ho fatto le solite cose: alzarmi, vestirmi, rifare il letto, fare colazione, controllare qualcosa su Internet, ecc.

> Ho fatto le solite cose: alzarmi, vestirmi, rifare il letto, fare colazione, controllare qualcosa su Internet, ecc..

I am used to write in American English, and I would probably not add the period. Reading *ecc..* seems strange to me.

Does the same apply when the sentence ends with ellipsis?

> Ho fatto le solite cose: alzarmi, vestirmi, rifare il letto, fare colazione, controllare qualcosa su Internet…

> Ho fatto le solite cose: alzarmi, vestirmi, rifare il letto, fare colazione, controllare qualcosa su Internet….

Comment: Why did you reject my edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as in English: there is no need to add another period in any case.
Regarding *ecc.* :

> - Se “ecc.” si trova a fine frase il punto fermo non va ripetuto. ([fonte](http://docenti.luiss.it/rocchini/suggerimenti-per-scrivere-la-tesi-di-laurea/norme-grafico-redazionali-per-tesisti/))
> - Se una frase termina con una abbreviazione (ecc., co.), il punto di quest’ultima vale anche come chiusura del periodo. ([fonte](http://publications.europa.eu/code/it/it-4100100.htm))

Regarding ellipsis:

> - I puntini di sospensione sono sempre e solo tre: dopo di essi, anche in fine di periodo, non occorre aggiungere il punto fermo. ([fonte](http://www.ocula.it/redazione/OCULA-Norme-generali-di-redazione.pdf))
> - I punti di sospensione sono sempre in numero di tre, sia che si trovino alla fine, all'inizio o all'interno di un periodo. ([fonte](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punti_di_sospensione))